# C# memcpy equivalent for vectors (C# List<T>) (Syntactic sugar)

Tags: c#, c++, memcpy, syntactic-sugar

I'm in the process of converting an old C++ library to C#.

The C++ library heavily relies on *overwriting* certain elements of a `std::vector<T>` by using `memcpy(&source[d_index],&source[s_index],count*sizeof(<T>));` (note that source and target are the same here, just different indices)

My C# port of this (by implementing `ICloneable` and `source` obviously being a `List<T>` where `T` is a reference type) is:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    source[d_index + i] = source[s_index + i].Clone();
```

**This works as supposed.**

However, my question is: Is there a simpler version? I obviously can't use `List.InsertRange(d_index, List.GetRange(s_index, count))` because this method *inserts* instead of overwrite.

I can't use `List<T>.CopyTo Method (Int32, T[], Int32, Int32)` either as the destination has to be an array of `T[]` and not the list itself.

Is there a method that does what `memcpy` does for this specific example? I know I could easily implement an extension method myself, I was just wondering if I missed something on MSDN.

Comment: Why would you want to do something like this? What is the purpose of the `memcpy`? Remove items? Add items? C# abstracts the actual memory locations of the elements so that you can concentrate on the real problem instead. Concentrate on the purpose of `memcpy` and then implement the behaviour in C# instead of the exact functionality.

Comment: For the specific problem at hand, I need to take _n_ elements from a list at a certain starting position and overwrite _n_ elements at a certain destination position of the same list. This is about computer graphics if that was your question.

Comment: Life without a garbage collector is not that simple, C++ code tends to do a lot of copying to simplify the memory management.  Particularly so for collections in older pre-C++11 code.  If you blindly reproduce the C++ code then you tend to start thinking you need Clone().  Which is a bad idea, it is very rarely needed in pure C# code.

Comment: @HansPassant I need to use clone because I A) have to store the original values, just at a different position, and B)  immediately modify those values (the original ones, not the clones) afterwards. That's how my alogrithm works and there's no way around that.

Comment: Well, just add a constructor that takes an object of the same class.  In effect you're duplicating a C++ copy constructor.

Comment: I just feel the need to point out that this is bad C++ code and will crash and burn as soon as you use it with anything other than plain old data structs. You should always use `std::copy` or `std::vector::insert` in C++ as it will do the right thing.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your feedback! In my ICloneable implementation I'm just calling Object.MemberwiseClone(). From the methodology's point of view this does exactly what a copy constructor does. Why is the former a bad idea when the latter isn't? What I mean is why is .Clone() a bad idea?

Comment: Well, not exactly, you get a shallow copy.  In other words, you copy the fields, but you don't create a copy of an object that's referenced by the field.  Which is also the problem with Clone(), it doesn't tell the cloner whether a deep or a shallow copy is required.  The memcpy() hack is very troublesome for the same reason, also always a shallow copy.  Lethal in C++ if the object contains pointers.  Hard to put lipstick on that pig of course, but you'll at least avoid the dangling pointer problem in C#.  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this problem myself and i came to the same conclusion either use Clone or make a copy constructor yourself.

For the CopyTo method i forgot but doesnt it just copy the references again? Other then that you can save those into a array as you said and use AddRange(array).

Answer (score 0):

How about RemoveRange, followed by Insert range? Obviously only if the ranges do not overlap.

Comment: The key element here is I need to be able to set the starting index and destination index. Not just append at the end. Also, I don't ned a shallow copy as all C++ classes are value types.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that. Then how about the remove range option? Obviously only if the ranges do not overlap.